# How to write down form with varying rhyme schemes?

Tags: musical-forms, rhyme-schemes

I have a 16 bar verse for a song and I am trying to figure out how to write down the form **and rhyme schemes** so I can reuse rhyming patterns that I like in future songs.

So in my 16 bar verse my phrasing would be divided as follows

4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4

All the 4 bar phrases rhyme and the 2 X 2 bar phrases that have their own rhyme scheme in the middle. How can I write down these patterns and the rhyme schemes for future use? AABA' is almost right since all three 4 bar phrases rhyme and contain melodically similar material. The B section however doesn't say to me that those two bar phrases rhyme with each other. So would AABBA' be more correct? Except, if I read this months down the line I might think the B sections are as long as the A sections when they are not. I need a way of recording this so that I will remember

1. phrase length
2. phrase similarity
3. rhyme scheme

Comment: Well, maybe section B contrasts with section A in that section A uses aaaa rhyme scheme while section B uses aabb rhyme scheme, and also uses shorter phrases?

Comment: Section B contrasts with section A in that it is 2 X 2 bars with its own nested rhyme scheme. I am looking for the correct way of writing this I have given some examples of ways I thought about writing this and explained why they don't suffice.

Comment: From answers and comments: may be it‘s worth while adding a simple example of your texts or verses to your question, which help understanding your situation and final result? // In the Tex/Latex community this would be the analogy of posting code, to better understand trouble.

Comment: Continued: bar, AABA forms etc. To what extent do you relate your question to music and its tools for notation, e.g. staves, lead sheets, melodies, rhythmic notation etc.? Is such a framework necessary or nice to have? After all are you looking for your specific symbolic language?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach, buidling on percussive notation. For demonstration purposes I chose a limerick. You certainly can adjust further to your needs.

### Limerick

```
A dozen, a gross, and a score
Plus three times the square root of four
Divided by seven
Plus five times eleven
Is nine squared and not a bit more.
```

### Analysis

First let's have a look at the 5 lines. My indications:

- a slash `/` for each syllable
- replaced by indicators `A` and `B` for dedicated locations of the two different rhymes
- put `8` and `6` in the beginning to indicate the number of syllables per line

[image: analysis]

### Generalized structure or pattern

So, how can we generalize this pattern?

- it has two forms `[A]` and `[B]` (rehearsal marks)
- both repeat
- the finishing line follows form `[A]` again once AND rhymes on syllable `A`

Now you could use this as a blue-print for new limericks following the same pattern.

[image: generalized]

### Compared to your requirements

- *phrases*: see the 3 lines, forms `[A]` and `[B]` (rehearsal marks)
- *phrase length*: twofold: by digit `8`, `6`, and by length of lines
- *rhyme scheme*: characters `A` and `B` above the lines show, where two different rhymes have to happen

### Some discussion

Some Limericks vary both in number of syllables, repeat the finishing lines sometimes, which you can both draw as different blue-print patterns.

For example this one follows `8-8-5-5-8+8` syllables per line:

```
There was a young man from Japan
Whose limericks never would scan.
And when they asked why,
He said ”I do try!
But when I get to the last line I try to fit in as many words as I can.”
```

If you have a more granular verse, which e.g. runs over 4 bars for form `[A]`, and has more then 1 point-of-rhyme ... you just indicate that (sub-bars, more letters C, D, E ...).  E.g. you could easily incorporate the `xaxabbxa` scheme the way you need and which you liked.

Without knowing your texts I think this approach is both simple enough (shows the important structures) AND capable of more complexity (many syllables from 4 bars etc.).

For more complex schemes I'd condense or reduce the slashes `/` a bit more. After all, the structure, differences and similarities shall be visualized. Contrast above's  Japan-limerick with the beard-one:

[image: Japan short]

```
There was an old man with a beard,
A funny old man with a beard
He had a big beard
A great big old beard
That amusing old man with a beard.
```

[image: beard]

### Outlook

Let's see, how a blue-print for a more compelx rhyme pattern might stimulate a novice like me. A 1-liner, form `[C]`, for a 4-bar verse shall have this more complex structure:

[image: complex 1-liner]

or in an alternative layout:

[image: alternative layout]

So I first came up with the `D`-parts, and then with the `E`-parts like this:

```
Man from Eden, looking for a lovely wife, went to Sweden, finding not just one but five.
```

Is this verse old or new? I don't know, but (re-)invented it on-the-fly from said blue-print.

In terms of `music and melodies`, you might prefer a 4-8-4-8 = 3 x 8 measures pattern. Well, that's easy to do: we just identified 2 free measures, which could be used for a short fill, e.g. from guitar (1st, like *wring*) and drums (2nd, like *ta-toosh*) to enhance, underline or contrast the verses drama.

### References

- dozen, Japan and beard from [section Variations, Limerick, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_(poetry)#Variations)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to notate the rhyme scheme, notate it. If you want to notate the number of measures, number of phrase or something else, notate it. There is no rule saying that sections must be the same length, or that they must include the same number of lines, phrases, rhymes etc.

AABA form is popular and both musicians and the audience are familiar with it. The symmetric number of measures in each section supports this division, even if the B section has a different internal structure. It is actually common for the section B to contrast with section A in many ways, including the phrasing and the rhyme scheme.

As all rules can be broken in art, I can imagine that there might be the cases when one would prefer to split the B section into two shorter sections, but I don't find such reason in your description.

Edit:
OK, following the discussion, I may understand better the issue.

So there are several quite distinct concepts here:

1. Lyric line lengths. They are based on the number of stressed syllables. For example, in a phrase

**How** to **write down form** with **var**ying **rhyme** **schemes**?

I would find 7 stressed syllables, as marked with the bold font. Though I could imagine someone doing it differently, I don't like to start an argument about the correctness of my choice.

2. Length of the melody
3. Rhythm of the melody

and finally...

4. Matching lyrics stresses with music accents.

So there are really many variables. A skilled songwriter will use them all consistently, or not, as needed. A less skilled one may have less control over it.

When notating the rhymes, the line lengths are not really considered, so your verse would look as:

a
a
b
b
a

Maybe you *could* treat your 4 bar "A" sections as consisting of two lines, then the rhyme scheme could represent all 2-bar lines:

x
a
x
a
b
b
x
a

where x stands for lack of rhyme. But that's a question to you – do you consider the non-rhyming phrase a separate line, or not. This may actually more depend on the lyrical, than the musical content.

You *could* try to additionally present the numbers of measures in each of the phrases, e.g.:

```
- - - - (a)
- - - - (a)
- -     (b)
- -     (b)
- - - - (a)
```

but does it make sense? It mixes up the lyric rhymes with music phrase lengths. Maybe it's useful, maybe not.

Maybe you would like to notate the numbers of stressed syllables in each line instead?

There might be not a single best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I would like to notate the rhyme scheme as I have written and have not come up with a solution as to how to do that. I was asking how to do this in my post.

Comment: @armani I don't fully understand your description. What rhymes with what. What does it mean "all 4 bar phrases rhyme"? Is there a single word in the first A that rhymes with another word in the second A? So is the complete rhyme scheme for the verse aabba? Note the letters here don't represent sections, but lines

Comment: Yes exactly! I want a way to say that the b's are shorter than the a's.. Do you understand? Musically they are not the same length and I want to record this and write it down so that it makes sense to me later and to anyone else that may read it

Comment: @armani - Good point - the top Google search results I get for `limerick rhyme scheme` say its rhyme scheme is AABBA...complete with all B lines being half the length of the A lines.

Comment: ok thanks but is there a way to write it so that it is clear that the B is half of A?

Comment: @armani I added some more discussion, but it might be not what you hoped for....

Comment: Thank you. I see now that this is not usually done, or that there is no real universal method to work with these variables. I do like your xaxabbxa idea because that shows me where the rhymes are do thank you. I dont know why line lengths are not considered because in music that is the most important thing!

Comment: It seems silly to me just saying aabba because how on earth will I know that I meant that the verse should be 4 bars not 5?

Comment: @armani you wouldn't. You need to notate it in another way. In the updated answer, I showed an example of how to do it, but this is not really a common way, as, what I also tried to explain, the length of music, expressed in measures, is not the same as the lyric line length.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of re-reading, I *think* what you're asking for is a system for visually representing phrase length. I think all the talk about rhyme is throwing people off; rhyme is simply rhyme, and the whole AABB thing simply indicates that there are words that rhyme. I'm not aware of a system for poetry that reflects line length. For music, though, I've seen phrase length indicated simply with giant slurs over the connected bars. You could even show these slurs without the musical notation, just indicating phrase length by the relative size. So, for instance, your 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 pattern might look like:

[image]